# Can I use Google Ads on a game published on non-Google platforms?

Tags: unity, google-play, monetization, advertisements

I just made a game with unity personal. And I want to publish/release it on sites like Getjar, Aptoide, Slideme etc. instead of Play Store.

So I want to know if I can still get revenue from Google ads or if I have to publish it on the play store to get revenue from ads.

Comment: By the way, [Unity also has an own advertisement system](https://unity.com/solutions/unity-ads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can earn revenue from Google Mobile Ads on other stores, or even if you just distribute the app yourself by uploading the apk somewhere online.

This is obviously also true in the case of iOS apps.